# Probability triangle question?

Tags: probability

We have five segments with the length 1cm  3 cm 5 cm 7 cm and 9 cm.Find the probability that if we choose three segments by chance,we have a triangle.
My idea:To form a triangle,the length of one segment,should be smaller than the sum of the other two segments..now what?

Comment: If we choose $1$ we are in deep trouble. So it better be from $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$. If we pick $3$, we are OK unless $\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, $3$ segments form a triangle if and only if the length of each one is less than the sum of others' length.

Next, it's easy to count all the variations which do not form a triangle.
Once you have counted them, use the following formula to get the probability of having a non-triangle:
$$P=\frac{\text{count of non-triangles}}{\text{count of all possible variations}}$$
And the probability of having a triangle is equal to $1$ minus the probability of NOT having a triangle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is asking about how check if three segments can be a triangle in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Segments: 
$\overline{A,A^\prime}$ with length $1cm$, 
$\overline{B,B^\prime}$ with length $3cm$
$\overline{C,C^\prime}$ with length $5cm$, 
$\overline{D,D^\prime}$ with length $7cm$, 
$\overline{E,E^\prime}$ with length $9cm$.

Notation: $\Delta( X, Y, Z)$ is a trianble of sites $\overline{X,X^\prime}$, $\overline{Y,Y^\prime}$  and $\overline{Z,Z^\prime}$.

We must consider the triangle inequality.

[image]

- we have a total of zero triangles in the form $\Delta(A,Y,Z)$ by cause triangle inequalitie fall for all $Y$ and $Z$.
- we have a total of 2 triangles in the form $\Delta(B,Y,Z)$ by cause triangle inequalitie no fall for $\Delta( B,C,D)$, $\Delta( B,D,E)$.
- we have a total of 1 triangles in the form $\Delta(C,D,E)$ by cause triangle inequalitie no fall for $\Delta( C,D,E)$.

We have $\frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!}=10 $ possibilities to choose three segimentos a total of 5 segments. And we have a total of 3 triangles. Therefore the probability is $1-\frac{3}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Count the number of triples that satisfy the [Triangle Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) and divide by the total number of triples. For example: $7\lt3+5$ and $9\lt5+7$.

The total number of triples is $\binom{5}{3}$.